# Silence output from selenium (webdriver) when running behat tests

Tags: testing, selenium, behat

I have written Behat tests which run Selenium. However the tests are quite noisy on the command line with a lot of messages about which file are found --> see https://travis-ci.org/lsolesen/panopoly/builds/14898467. Really just notices about 200 HTTP codes.

Tests can be found here: https://github.com/lsolesen/panopoly/blob/landingpage/ and .travis.yml holds the code for the test-run.

How can I silence the tests, so only the relevant output like errors and warnings are shown for the Selenium / Webdriver?